# Accessing a dynamically created multi dimensional array with pointers arithmetic

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, dynamically-generated, pointer-arithmetic

I would like to understand how does it works to scan a dynamically allocated two-dimensional array using pointers arithmetics?

I can't figurate why in my example pointer arithmetic isn't returning the same results as using array indexing.

Here is my implementation:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

void init_matrix(int ** m, int size);
void print_matrix(int ** m, int size);
void print_matrix_pointers(int ** m, int size);

int main (){
    srand (time(NULL));
    int size = 3;
    int ** dynamic_matrix = new int * [size];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        dynamic_matrix[i] = new int [size];
    }
    init_matrix(dynamic_matrix, size);
    
    cout << "Dynamic matrix accessed using square brackets ([i][j]): " << endl;
    print_matrix(dynamic_matrix, size);

    cout << "Dynamic matrix accessed using pointers arithmetics: " << endl;
    print_matrix_pointers(dynamic_matrix, size);

    return 0;

}

void init_matrix(int ** m, int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            m[i][j] = rand()%10;
        }
    }
}

void print_matrix(int ** m, int size){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            cout << m[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}


void print_matrix_pointers(int ** m, int size){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            cout << *(*m + (i * size) + j) << " "; //
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

For instance if size was 3 I would get this output.

Dynamic matrix accessed using array indexing ([i][j]):

3 3 4

9 5 9

4 9 4

Dynamic matrix accessed using pointers arithmetics:

3 3 4

32735 9 5

9 32735 4

Comment: `int size = 3;` but `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {` thats undefined behavior. Output of the code could be anything.

Comment: Thanks i forgot to change that.

Comment: please dont fix errors in the quesiton. The question is for the broken code. Corrected code goes to answers

Comment: If you use `std::vector` and appropriate functions and statements (like [range `for` loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)), you can avoid many problems.

Comment: Could you please clarify the question to explain that you are trying to understand why your pointer arithmetic example is not returning the same results as your array indexing?

Comment: Looks like the only thing C++ about this is the use of `cout`.  replace with `printf`s and this could be retagged C.

Answer (score 2):

With `*(*m + (i * size) + j)` you treat `m` as a contiguous array of values, which it isn't. It's more like a [jagged array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array). You need to treat it like the array of pointers it really is, like `*(*(m + i) + j)`.

Answer (score 1):

Two typos in your code:

```
int size = 3;
int ** dynamic_matrix = new int * [size];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    dynamic_matrix[i] = new int [size];
}
```

`size` is `3` but you write `10` elements. That is undefined behavior.

Then you are advancing the pointer wrongly.

```
void print_matrix_pointers(int ** m, int size){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            cout << *( *(m + i) + j) << " "; //
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

`m` points to an array of pointers to `int`. You have to increment `m` by `i` to get to the `i`-th row. Then you want to access the `j`th element of the array pointed to by `m[i]`, hence you have to first dereference `m+i` then add `j` to get the address of `j`th element.